# Sending a mail inside a scheduled (cron) shell script does not work

Tags: cron, raspbian, ssmtp

I have a shell script with the following content

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo Rscript /home/username/RWD/test.R
sudo find /home/username/RWD -type f -name "*.png" -exec /usr/bin/mpack -s "Test Mail" {} my.email@provider.de \;
sudo find /home/username/RWD -type f -name "*.png" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

So I just execute a R script which produces an image file (*.png). This file is send via mail and deleted afterwards.

This works fine when I execute the script in the command line. But when I use cron to schedule the script, the content of the mail is what R is printing in its console:

```
Lade nötiges Paket: xml2

Attache Paket: ‘zoo’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

   as.Date, as.Date.numeric

Warnmeldungen:
1: Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
2: Removed 5 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

Any idea why the scheduled script behaves differently?

Comment: I don't think that cron will be able to guess that it should execute everything in the same current working directory and keep the state of the CWD.  cron does limit the CWD considerably.  Instead do an `mktemp -d` and place the file in there (pass the result of mktemp to each part of the script).

Comment: @grochmal Ok thanks. I will give it a shot.

Comment: @grochmal Since I am a shell noob I didn't really got the `mktemp` attempt working. I now ended up with calling `cd /home/username/RWD && {MYCODE}` prior to every line in my shell script. That works for me right now. Thank's for guiding me towards the CWD problem! (If you want to work your `mktemp` comment out as an answer, I will gladly accept it).